# \pgfmathdectobase macro \pgfmathresult digit index or bitwise operators

Tags: foreach, strings, arrays, pgfmath

Is there a way to access each digit of a macro returned by `\pgfmathdectobase` (or `\pgfmathresult`) which is a binary number ? This would be useful for a function which prints the power set of a given set (according to binary representations of numbers between `0` and `2^|given set|`).

I can think of two versions 1) convert macro to an array and loop or 2) calculate size of macro and loop with `\foreach` if there is way to access the digits. Unfortunately I was not able to find anything near in the pgfmanual.

Also another possible solution would be with bit-masks. Does tikz support anything like that? Or any idea on a package that does?

I would be happy with any other package that can use the results from `\pgfmathdectobase`, too, if there is way to use it outside of tikz. Thanks!

Comment: I have been using the `{xstring}` package for traversing strings, so think that you should be able to traverse it with `\StrLeft` along with `\StrGobbleLeft`.

Comment: can you perhaps clarify what you are trying to do with the digits when "accessing" them?

Comment: @Bruno yes sure. I'm trying to build a function which prints the power set of a given set and figured, mapping binary digits from 0 to 2^|given set| to individual sets would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to examine bit by bit the number, the scheme might be like this

```
\def\temp{10111}
\newcount\bitnumber
\def\slowbinary#1{%
  \ifx\relax#1% end
  \else
    \advance\bitnumber by 1
    \ifcase#1\relax\docasezero\or\docaseone\fi
  \expandafter\slowbinary
  \fi}
\def\processbinary#1{\bitnumber=-1 % reset the counter (we will start at 0)
  \expandafter\slowbinary#1\relax}

\def\docasezero{\message{^^JZero seen}}
\def\docaseone{\message{^^JOne seen}}

\processbinary\temp
\processbinary{1010}
```

In case you need to start from the less significant bit, you have to reverse the number first.

```
\makeatletter
\def\processbinaryrev#1{%
  \bitnumber=-1 % reset the counter (we will start at 0)
  \@reverse{#1}%
  \expandafter\slowbinary\@esrever \relax}

\def\@reverse#1{%
  \edef\@temp{#1}%
  \def\@esrever{}%
  \loop\unless\ifx\@temp\@empty
    \edef\@esrever{\expandafter\@car\@temp\@nil\@esrever}%
    \edef\@temp{\expandafter\@cdr\@temp\@nil}%
  \repeat}
\makeatother

\processbinaryrev\temp
```

There are many loops around for reversing strings. Maybe also PGF has some.

Instead of `\temp` you can use `\pgfmathresult` or the first argument to `\pgfmathdectobase`.

Of course you'll give more meaningful actions to `\docasezero` and `\docaseone`; these actions can use the value of `\bitnumber`. You can define a set of macros as

```
\def\docasezero{\csname casezero\romannumeral\bitnumber\endcsname}
\def\docaseone{\csname caseone\romannumeral\bitnumber\endcsname}

\def\casezero{What to do when bit 0 is 0}
\def\caseone{What to do when bit 0 is 1}
\def\casezeroi{What to do when bit 1 is 0}
\def\caseonei{What to do when bit 1 is 1}
\def\casezeroii{What to do when bit 2 is 0}
\def\caseoneii{What to do when bit 2 is 1}
...
```

Here is a complete example (where I've changed a bit the programming style, using `@` and constants provided by the LaTeX kernel):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcount\@bitnumber

\def\@slowbinary#1{%
  \ifx\relax#1% end
  \else
    \advance\@bitnumber\@ne
    \ifcase#1\relax\do@casezero\or\do@caseone\fi
  \expandafter\@slowbinary
  \fi}

\def\@reverse#1{%
  \edef\@temp{#1}%
  \def\@esrever{}%
  \loop\unless\ifx\@temp\@empty
    \edef\@esrever{\expandafter\@car\@temp\@nil\@esrever}%
    \edef\@temp{\expandafter\@cdr\@temp\@nil}%
  \repeat}

% \def\processbinary#1{\@bitnumber\m@ne
%   \expandafter\@slowbinary#1\relax}

\def\processbinaryrev#1{\@reverse{#1}\@bitnumber=-1
  \expandafter\@slowbinary\@esrever \relax}

\def\do@casezero{\csname casezero\romannumeral\@bitnumber\endcsname\relax}
\def\do@caseone{\csname caseone\romannumeral\@bitnumber\endcsname\relax}

\makeatother

\def\casezero{What to do when bit 0 is 0\par}
\def\caseone{What to do when bit 0 is 1\par}
\def\casezeroi{What to do when bit 1 is 0\par}
\def\caseonei{What to do when bit 1 is 1\par}
\def\casezeroii{What to do when bit 2 is 0\par}
\def\caseoneii{What to do when bit 2 is 1\par}
\def\casezeroiii{What to do when bit 3 is 0\par}
\def\caseoneiii{What to do when bit 3 is 1\par}
\def\casezeroiv{What to do when bit 4 is 0\par}
\def\caseoneiv{What to do when bit 4 is 1\par}
\def\casezerov{What to do when bit 5 is 0\par}
\def\caseonev{What to do when bit 5 is 1\par}

\def\temp{10111}

\begin{document}

\temp

\processbinaryrev\temp

\bigskip

101110

\processbinaryrev{101110}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly fine for `\processbinaryrev` which is actually all I need. `\processbinary` causes some latex error. Unfortunately I barely understand the function ;) so I can't figure out where to put a counter such that I can remember the index of the digit recognized.

Comment: Indeed there was a typo in `\processbinary`, I'll correct it and show also how to add a counter for the "place".

Comment: @egreg Thanks for your edits! Is it possible the roman functions are never called? I've been trying to get them working but always the first two are called. Seems like bitnumber is not advanced, but I have no clue why not.

Comment: @panny: the place where I wrote `\bitnumber=-1` was wrong!

Comment: @egreg Is it possible to integrate `\bitnumber` into an outputting function like `\def\casezero{What to do when bit \bitnumber is 0\par}` this would be useful when the bitstring length is not known at the beginning.

Comment: When the bit number `\bitnumber` is examined, TeX executes `\do@casezero` or `\do@caseone`. You can define them as you like and the current value of `\bitnumber` is available. It depends mostly on the application you have in mind how to define those commands.

Comment: Actually I experimented with `\do@casezero` but I can't get the value of `\bitnumber` out if it. I tried just printing `\bitnumber`oder `\@bitnumber` inside `\do@casezero` (also tried `\value(\bitnumber)`oder `\value(bitnumber)` with no success. I guess it is always difficult to change code one does not really understand ;) I don't know what the @ does actually.

Comment: You access the value of `\@bitnumber` with `\the\@bitnumber`. The `@` is just not to clobber existing commands (that's why the code is between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. If you add some clarification to your question, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

From your sub-question about bit masks I assume that you are dealing with bin/oct/dec/hex bases only? If that is the case, I strongly recommend using the [bitset](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bitset) package by Heiko Oberdiek, which provides all common operators for bit-wise manipulation of data.